# How check is font a "latin extended" in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Is any way to check is font from latin extended family by using any method of Font class? For example I have a list of all fonts:

```
List<String> families = Font.getFamilies();
```

Is possibility to get from this list fonts which are latin extended coded ? For example that are fonts which have special characters like "ą, ę, ó, ł, ś, ć, ź".